# What happens when writing to pipe of size greater than the specified input data size?

Tags: linux, pipe, fork, system-calls, fwrite

In the below program when we try to print the buf from the read end of the pipe in the child process the string in printf gets appended to the buf. Please explain this behaviour.

```
/* pipe3.c */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int pipefds[2];
    pid_t pid;
    char buf[30];
    //create pipe
    if(pipe(pipefds) == -1){
        perror("pipe");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
      memset(buf,0,30);
      pid = fork();
    if (pid > 0) {
      printf(" PARENT write in pipe\n");
    //parent close the read end
          close(pipefds[0]);
    //parent write in the pipe write end                 
      write(pipefds[1], "SMAQ", 16);
    //after finishing writing, parent close the write end
          close(pipefds[1]);
    //parent wait for child                
      wait(NULL);                         
    }else {  
      //child read from the pipe read end until the pipe is empty 
      printf("pipefds[1] %d \n",pipefds[1]);
      printf("pipefds[0] %d \n",pipefds[0]);
    //   close(pipefds[1]);  
      while(read(pipefds[0], buf, 1)==1)   
        printf("CCHILD read from pipe -- %s\n", buf);
      //after finishing reading, child close the read end
      close(pipefds[0]);
      printf("CCHILD: EXITING!");
      exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Write in parent process returns 16( successfully 16 bytes written).

output for the above program

```
PARENT write in pipe
pipefds[1] 4 
pipefds[0] 3 
CCHILD read from pipe -- S
CCHILD read from pipe -- M
CCHILD read from pipe -- A
CCHILD read from pipe -- Q
CCHILD read from pipe -- 
CCHILD read from pipe -- p
CCHILD read from pipe -- i
CCHILD read from pipe -- p
CCHILD read from pipe -- e
CCHILD read from pipe -- f
CCHILD read from pipe -- d
CCHILD read from pipe -- s
CCHILD read from pipe -- [
CCHILD read from pipe -- 1
CCHILD read from pipe -- ]
CCHILD read from pipe --
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In C reading beyond the end of an array, such as a literal string is undefined behaviour.

```
write(pipefds[1], "SMAQ", 16);
```

Here `"SMAQ"` is only 5 bytes long (4 characters and a terminating zero), so the write continues to whatever is after the string in memory, the compiler has chosen to put `"pipefds[1] %d \n"` there.